# Diameter of a lens vs Diameter of the circular Aperture of the lens vs Aperture of the lens

Tags: lenses, optical-materials

I was reading about resolving power in which it is said that "a is the diameter of the circular aperture or the diameter of the lens, whichever is smaller" . So, I don't understand how are they not the same.
What is the difference between diameter of a lens, diameter of circular aperture of the lens and aperture of the lens? Please explain.

Comment: This question shows no research effort.

Comment: @ACuriousMind What research can I do about terminology?

Comment: An [aperture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperture) is not the lens itself. That should be easy to find out. What confuses you about the difference between a lens and the aperture?

Answer (score 5):

The diameter of the lens is its physical diameter.

[image]

It is sometimes advantageous to reduce the area through which the light travels and that is then the aperture.

In the case of resolving power making the aperture smaller reduces the resolving power which means it is more difficult if not impossible to distinguish between objects whose angular separation is small.

You may however have to reduce the size of the aperture if the light intensity is very large.  So there is a compromise to be reached.

@ArifBurhan 's answer explains how the size of the aperture is designated on a camera.

Answer (score 3):

Say you have a convex lens with a focal length of 50mm , standard on many SLR cameras, the diameter of the glass may be 30mm and there may be an aperture of 25mm , again diameter. In this setting the F-stop setting is   f-2 because 50/25 = 2 . This is why F-stop gets larger as aperture gets smaller.

Comment: Actually , this question is not that much related to photography, I was reading about resolving power in which it is said that "a is the diameter of the circular aperture of the diameter of the lens,whichever is smaller" . So , I don't understand how are they not same.

Comment: Diameter of lens is diameter of glass, diameter of aperture is diameter of hole , which is often smaller to give better resolution.

Comment: Which hole are you talking about?

Comment: @Quark say you are using a telescope it will be the narrowest part of the optical path.  Most camera lenses have a variable aperture to control light quantity and resolution.